# How to approxmate slope from a curvy graph?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How I can find the slope of the graph of at the following points:

[image]

---

My attempt to solve is as follows:

[image]

$m = \frac{(2.9 - 1.9)}{(0-3)} = \frac{1}{-3} = -0.33$

When I approximate these slopes my answers are nowhere near the answer in the solutions.

People have posted solutions to such questions at sites like [this](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780538497909-stewart-calculus-early-transcendentals-7th-edition/162/exercises/1a/#). But my question is how do they arrive at such accurate results?

---

**Update:**

Solutions provided by the book are as follows:

[image]

Comment: You should say what your answers are, and how you came to them. This will help people tailor their responses to best aid your understanding. Also, give the official solutions; it's possible there are errors.

Comment: Have you tried drawing approximation of the tangents to the curve for the values of $x$ given? Then you could calculate the slopes of these tangents.

Comment: @Blue I've updated the question, along with the answer.